# How to prevent app to publish except play store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish

I have published one application to the play store around 2 years ago. it has a good user base. But my problem is that I found my app on `apkpure` https://apkpure.com/ also where I have never uploaded. and I do not want my app to publish anywhere except play store. How can I remove my application from that other site? please advise.

Comment: The [Law Stack exchange site](https://law.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this question.